# How to use cron on a simple script

Tags: linux, cron, sh

I want to use cron for execute a script periodically. I want to try a simple script first but it does not work.

This is my script *(scritp.sh)* which permission are 700:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
echo "Hello!"
mkdir Hello
```

And this is the *crontab* file when I edit it with the command *crontab -e*:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
* * * * * /home/padro/Documents/script.sh
```

EDIT:
I have that script on */home/padro/Documents* folder. What I do after it is execute the command *crontab -e* for modify the cron file. In this file I put the shell that I want *SHELL=/bin/sh* and also the cron schedule expression  * * * * * /home/padro/Documents/script.sh. This schedule teorically run the script every minute. Finally I save the file and when a minute passes I can't see the echo of the script on the terminal.

EDIT2:
I have added *mkdir hello*, because I don't know if the echo of the script is shown on the terminal. But the hello directory is never created.

Comment: try using cron like this: `* * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/padro/Documents/script.sh`

Comment: @Padro What makes you think you should see the output in your (or any) terminal?

Comment: @Biffen I don't know, it is the first time that I use cron. I suppose that if I put an echo on the script when the cron runs it the echo shows the content on terminal.

Comment: @Padro It will print to *its* STDOUT, which is (most likely) not your terminal. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40623/where-does-the-output-of-at-and-cron-jobs-go

Comment: @Biffen ok, I understand it. The cron is working well and also the script but the output is not shown on my terminal. That's my error. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any output generated by a program called from cron will by default be emailed to the user owning the crontab (assuming local delivery of mail messages is possible).  So I'd suggest that you look in your inbox on the local machine.

To save the output into a file, use a redirection in the crontab, or arrange for the script to write its output to a file.

Jobs started by cron does not run with a terminal, so you should not expect to see your terminal being cleared every minute by running this script through cron.

The `Hello` folder should have been created in the working directory used by the script (possibly your home directory).  To make absolutely sure you know where the script's working directory is, use `cd` in the script to move to the correct location.

Answer (score -1):

I do not have enough reputation to add comment.

My humble comment would be.
Is the cron file you mentioned via root?

cos **chmod 700 a file would be only be executed by *owner*.** 
If you are using redhat linux, the user account you use on the first log in is user rights NOT root.

Reference [link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdb) to a cheat sheet.

**su - root**
system will prompt root password

**crontab -e**

*** * * * * /home/padro/Documents/script.sh**

You can even run a test script, which I did encounter the similar situation as you when I first learnt scripting into your crontab-

*** * * * * date > export/home/padro/Documents/testing.txt**

If you could, restart the server.

Check if your directory is correct using the command
**pwd** in linux/unix.

I hope my comment based on my recent learning have helped you.

Edit 1: Remove clear in your script. Thanks...
Edit 2: I believe your Hello folder is created at the core of the root folder try looking for it... or the home directory of the user...